# Creating a method to handle all Types of Swing Components

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

In order to save some time when setting the size of Swing Components (JPanel, JLabel, etc.), I am trying to write a method that when called, will set that component's size using 3 of the standard size-defining functions.

I would like to be able to do this:

```
import CustomComponents;
...
 JPanel xPanel = new JPanel();
 CSize.setDefiniteSize(xPanel, 400, 300);
...
```

Or (and preferably)

```
...
 JPanel xPanel = new JPanel();
 xPanel.CSize.setDefiniteSize(400, 300);
...
```

Here's the code I have so far.  The problem is, I want the method to be functional for all types of Swing components, and it seems to only work for the one I specify in the heading.

```
package CustomComponents;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class CSize
{
public static void setDefiniteSize(JComponent c, int h, int w)
{
    Dimension k = new Dimension (h, w);
    c.setMaximumSize(k);
    c.setMinimumSize(k);
    c.setPreferredSize(k);
}
}
```

As you can see, here I tried using JComponent, but it won't work, as whatever I use it with - say a JPanel - is a JPanel, not a JComponent (even though it's a subclass?  I still don't get how this works)

Comment: can you post an exact error/exception ?

Comment: method setDefiniteSize in class CustomComponents.CSize cannot be applied to given types;

required: javax.swing.JComponent,init,init;  found: javax.swing.JFrame.int,int;  reason: actual argument javax.swing.JFrame cannot be converted to javax.swing.JComponent by method invocation conversion

Comment: `JFrame` _is not_ a `JComponent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `java.awt.Container`, because JFrame is not a direct subclass of `JComponent`!

So it should work with the following code:

```
package CustomComponents;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class CSize {
    public static void setDefiniteSize(Container c, int h, int w) {
        Dimension k = new Dimension (h, w);
        c.setMaximumSize(k);
        c.setMinimumSize(k);
        c.setPreferredSize(k);
    }
}
```

Look at the hierarchy of the components:

```
java.awt.Component
  |--java.awt.Container
       |--java.awt.Window
       |    |--java.awt.Frame
       |         |--javax.swing.JFrame
       |--javax.swing.JComponent
            |--javax.swing.JLabel
```

Even better would be using `java.awt.Component`, since this class is defining all methods you want to use ([setMinimumSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setMinimumSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29), [setMaximumSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setMaximumSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) and [setPreferredSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29)).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! I didn't think outside the box, so I only wanted to explain how the components fit in their hierarchy. But it's a good point to mention!

Answer (score 2):

Though what you're trying to do, you may think is crafty, but you may find it later to be discouraging trying to size everything

See this thread [**Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/2587435)

Instead you should make use of LayoutManagers. and `.pack()` the frame. Swing was made to be used with LayoutManager. You need to take into account that your program may look good on your development screen, but may look different on others. You will also find out that many LayoutManegers will not even respect your preferred size, so you need to learn which ones do and which ones don't. Here's a [**simple example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376596/2587435)

With layout managers, you let the layouts do all the sizing for you. Some layouts will stretch your components, some center them in open spaces. Your program will be a lot more fluid if you use them.

See [**Laying out Components Within a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details on how you can use them.

Comment: @Scott: Layouts are the right choice; don't do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513).