# Why does my JButton appear the full size of the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, layout-manager

I am a newbie, I have a question. I am trying to use Eclipse to write a Java windows application, in which I will have a main window, which will contain several things, like a dashboard sort of thing, and it will have buttons, for example to add a record to a database, and this button when pressed, will open a new relevant window on top.

I tried to start, I wrote this code in Java, and for some reason, the button is in the size of the frame...full screen ! How do I fix it ?

Can you suggest me better ideas for a design than what I specified ?

Thank you

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    JFrame  jfrm = new JFrame("Frame1");
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    jfrm.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabel jlab = new JLabel("Hello");
    jfrm.add(jlab);

    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    button.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    button.setLocation(500, 350);
    jfrm.getContentPane().add(button);

    jfrm.setVisible(true);  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a layout to the JFrame first. For example `FlowLayout`:

```
jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

Answer (score 4):

> "I tried to start, I wrote this code in Java, and for some reason, the button is in the size of the frame...full screen ! How do I fix it ?"

The reason the button stretches is because `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout` that does not respect the preferred sizes of child components.

The solution is to set the Layout Manager to layout that *does* respect preferred sizes. The image blow from [**this example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376596/2587435) shows the most common Layout Managers and show visually which one respect the preferred size of child components.

Also, the `BorderLayout` is also the reason your `JLabel` does not show. By default, every component that is added to a `BorderLayout` without a position specified e.g. `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, will automatically be placed in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position. Each position may only have one component. So when you add the `JLabel` it goes to the `CENTER`, but when you add the `JButton`, it also goes the `CENTER`, kicking out the `JLabel`.

If you've never encountered Layout Managers, this is probably all confusing to you. You should take the time to go over [**How to Layout Components Within a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some form of layoutmanager, you can use this information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score -1):

You must use [Layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Use this code..

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{

JFrame  jfrm = new JFrame("Frame1");
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
jfrm.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JLabel jlab = new JLabel("Hello");
jfrm.add(jlab);

JButton button = new JButton("Button");
button.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
button.setLocation(500, 350);
jfrm.add(button);
jfrm.setVisible(true);  
jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
jfrm.pack();
```

you forgot to add `pack()`. so use this code to get Jlabel and JButtion side by side.

Thanks...