# Change Background Color on JFrame in this context?

Tags: java, swing

When I run this program the color doesn't change to blue. How do I change the color in this context? Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JPanel {
 static void test() {
  JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
  f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
  f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  f.getContentPane().add(new Test());
  f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
  f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        test();
     }
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: instead of using the getContentPane(), just do setBackground(Color.BLUE); * may be setBackgroundColor, can't remember, but use caps for the color.*

Answer (score 1):

I think your new Test() is overlapping the background color.

Try to change the jpanels background color.

Answer (score 1):

The `setBackground` works fine. The problem is with the default `BorderLayout` of the `JFrame`. The only component you add is the `Test` `JPanel` which get expanded the size of the `JFrame`, due the `BorderLayout`, which ultimately covers up background color. If you take out the `Test` `JPanel` you will see the background color.

You can also see the affect, below, of setting the layout to `GridBagLayout` to the frame and setting a `preferredSize to the`JPanel`

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Test extends JPanel {
    public Test() {
        setBorder(new TitledBorder("Panel size 300, 300"));
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }

    @Override 
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    static void test() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new Test());
        f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

The reason `GridbagLayout` works is because it respects the `preferredSize` of child components. As you can see from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376596/2587435), some Layout Managers respect the preferred sizes and some don't

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set layout to `JFrame`

`f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`