# Fix the size of content in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

when I increase and decrease the size of frame by cursor , all the contents within JFrame should increase and decrease with the JFrame. If I fix the size of other component within frame, it should increase but should not decrease from its fixed size.

Comment: *"..I need to fix the size"*  We need a question.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Two words [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21376596/2587435) to see which ones with stretch your components.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson i dont get you, plz explain...

Comment: Your statements contradict each other. **1)** _"I need to fix the size of Jpanel, Textbox, button"_ **2)** _"when I increase and decrease the size of frame by cursor , all the contents within JFrame increase and decrease"_

Comment: @peeskillet  That is not i want. It should not decrease from fixed size  which is given for other component inside the frame.

Comment: You need to ask a question, if there is a problem you are facing. What you have so far is a **story**

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for how to ask a good question.

Comment: I read it as: "all items need to scale with the frame. Except if I fix the size of an item, in which case it can only increase in size, but not decrease beyond the minimum." All of which is doable, and most of which is supported by default with GUI components when added to a frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), only then all the components inside it will resize with the parent frame. (Also it will try to keep the ratio, depending on manager you choose) There are good examples on this link, first write simple layouts and then make more complex. If this was your question in the first place of course.