# Strange setBackground() error - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, setbackground

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JFrameGUI extends JFrame 
{
    JLabel item1;
    public JFrameGUI(int l, int b , String Title)
    {
        setTitle(Title);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(l, b);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        item1 = new JLabel("This is a Sentence.");
        item1.setToolTipText("This is gonna show up on hover.");
        add(item1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrameGUI g = new JFrameGUI(1280,720,"The End Of The Line");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        g.add(p);
    }
}
```

When I execute this  , all i get is a tiny Blue square nest to the "This is a sentence" string . I've tried everything !

Comment: This is unrelated, but in the future you may want to learn about [the Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), and why it is bad to manipulate Swing components outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the layout of the frame to a layout that `doesn't` respect the preferred sizes of its children. `FlowLayout` does, and your `JPanel` has no preferred size without any components added to it, or specifying a preferred size.

A simple fix, set the layout of the frame to `BorderLayout`, or not set a layout at all, since `JFrame` already has a default `BorderLayout`. Note though that you probably want to add the `JLabel` to the `JPanel` and not the `JFrame`. Unless you *do* want to add it the `JFrame` and not the background `JPanel`, you need to specify a `BorderLayout` position for the one you don't want in the center.

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376596/2587435) to see which layout managers respect preferred sizes and which don't

See more at [Layout out Components Withing a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Also, `setVisible(true)` shoul be the *last* thing you do *after* adding all components.