# Laying out a keyboard in Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I've been trying to reproduce this layout:

[image]

Here I am:

[image]

using:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Keyb {

    private JFrame f = new JFrame("Keyboard");

    private JPanel keyboard = new JPanel();

    private static final String[][] key = {
        {"`", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "=", "Backspace"},
        {"Tab", "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "[", "]", "\\"},
        {"Caps", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", ";", "'", "Enter"},
        {"Shift", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", ",", ".", "/", "Shift", "\u2191"},
        {" ", "\u2190", "\u2193", "\u2192"}
    };

    public Keyb() {
        keyboard.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel pRow;
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.weightx = 1d;

        for (int row = 0; row < key.length; ++row) {
            pRow = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            c.gridy = row;

            for (int col = 0; col < key[row].length; ++col)
                pRow.add(new JButton(key[row][col]));

            keyboard.add(pRow, c);
        }

        f.add(keyboard);
    }

    public void launch() {
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Keyb ui = new Keyb();
        ui.launch();
    }
}
```

How do I adjust the size of the buttons and align them perfectly, especially `Tab`, `Caps`, `Shift`, `Backspace`, `Enter` and the spacebar, perhaps without using the set?Size methods?

Can it be done in a better way with other layout managers?

New at Java, so any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As a starting point, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394845/space-button-size-on-my-layout-keyboard-wont-resize/22395483#22395483) might help

Comment: Well, the `Tab` and the `Caps` key are at 1.5 gridwidth, but the gridwidth is an integer.

Comment: You can kind of "cheat", but allowing the first key to have a `gridwidth` of `1` and the rest to have `2` it can allow components to "overlap", kind of...

Comment: Does it have to be "hacky"? Also, what can I do for vertical height?

Comment: Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Do you think I'd be here if I did?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When all else fails, write it your self...

[image: Keyboard]

This uses a custom layout manager which defines a "basic" grid but allows components in a given row to expand into portions of the following column(s)...

The default cell size is defined by the largest width/height of the available components that doesn't expand beyond it's own column, makes things a little more even.

Currently the output is anchored to the top/left corner, but I'm sure you can figure out how to calculate the x/y offset needed to get it centered ;)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.LayoutManager2;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Keyb {

    private static final Key[][] keys = new Key[][]{
        {
            createKey("`", 0, 0),
            createKey("1", 0, 1),
            createKey("2", 0, 2),
            createKey("3", 0, 3),
            createKey("4", 0, 4),
            createKey("5", 0, 5),
            createKey("6", 0, 6),
            createKey("7", 0, 7),
            createKey("8", 0, 8),
            createKey("9", 0, 9),
            createKey("0", 0, 10),
            createKey("-", 0, 11),
            createKey("=", 0, 12),
            createKey("Backspace", 0, 13, 2d)},
        {
            createKey("Tab", 1, 0, 1.5d),
            createKey("W", 1, 2),
            createKey("E", 1, 3),
            createKey("R", 1, 4),
            createKey("T", 1, 5),
            createKey("Y", 1, 6),
            createKey("U", 1, 7),
            createKey("I", 1, 8),
            createKey("O", 1, 9),
            createKey("P", 1, 10),
            createKey("[", 1, 11),
            createKey("]", 1, 12),
            createKey("\\", 1, 13)
        },
        {
            createKey("Caps", 2, 0, 1.5d),
            createKey("A", 2, 2),
            createKey("S", 2, 3),
            createKey("D", 2, 4),
            createKey("F", 2, 5),
            createKey("G", 2, 6),
            createKey("H", 2, 7),
            createKey("J", 2, 8),
            createKey("K", 2, 9),
            createKey("L", 2, 10),
            createKey(";", 2, 11),
            createKey("'", 2, 12),     
            createKey("Enter", 2, 13, 2d)
        },
        {
            createKey("Shift", 3, 0, 2d),
            createKey("Z", 3, 2),
            createKey("X", 3, 3),
            createKey("C", 3, 4),
            createKey("V", 3, 5),
            createKey("B", 3, 6),
            createKey("N", 3, 7),
            createKey("M", 3, 8),
            createKey(",", 3, 9),
            createKey(".", 3, 10),
            createKey("/", 3, 11),
            createKey("fill", 3, 12, 0.5d),
            createKey("\u2191", 3, 13),
        },
        {
            createKey("fill", 4, 0, 4d),
            createKey(" ", 4, 1, 6d),
            createKey("fill", 4, 2, 1.5d),
            createKey("\u2190", 4, 3),
            createKey("\u2193", 4, 4),
            createKey("\u2192", 4, 5),
        },
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Keyb();
    }

    public Keyb() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new KeyBoardLayout());
            for (int row = 0; row < keys.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < keys[row].length; col++) {
                    Key key = keys[row][col];
                    add(createButton(key.getText()), key.getKeyConstraint());
                }
            }
        }

        protected JComponent createButton(String text) {
            JComponent comp = null;
            if (text == null || text.equalsIgnoreCase("fill")) {
                comp = new JLabel();
            } else {
                comp = new JButton(text);
            }
            return comp;
        }

    }

    public static Key createKey(String text, int x, int y, double span) {
        return new Key(text).setKeyConstraint(new KeyConstraint(x, y, span));
    }

    public static Key createKey(String text, int x, int y) {
        return new Key(text).setKeyConstraint(new KeyConstraint(x, y));
    }

    public static class Key {

        private String text;
        private KeyConstraint keyConstraint;

        public Key(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public Key setKeyConstraint(KeyConstraint keyConstraint) {
            this.keyConstraint = keyConstraint;
            return this;
        }

        public KeyConstraint getKeyConstraint() {
            return keyConstraint;
        }

    }

    public static class KeyConstraint {

        public int row, column;
        public double span = 1d;

        public KeyConstraint(int row, int column) {
            this.row = row;
            this.column = column;
        }

        public KeyConstraint(int row, int column, double span) {
            this.row = row;
            this.column = column;
            this.span = span;
        }

    }

    public class KeyBoardLayout implements LayoutManager2 {

        private Map<Component, KeyConstraint> mapComponents;
        private Map<KeyConstraint, Component> mapConstraints;
        private Matrix<Integer, List<JComponent>> matrix = new Matrix<>(); // Virtual grid...

        private Dimension gridSize;

        public KeyBoardLayout() {
            mapComponents = new HashMap<>(25);
            mapConstraints = new HashMap<>(25);
        }

        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("addLayoutComponent(String, Comp) is not supported");
        }

        @Override
        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
            KeyConstraint kc = mapComponents.get(comp);
            mapComponents.remove(comp);
            if (kc != null) {
                mapConstraints.remove(kc);
                getCellContents(matrix, kc).remove(comp);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            int rowHeight = getRowHeight();
            Dimension size = new Dimension();
            size.width = getMaxRowWidth();
            size.height = rowHeight * matrix.getRowCount();
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return preferredLayoutSize(parent);
        }

        protected List<JComponent> getCellContents(Matrix matrix, KeyConstraint constraint) {
            return getCellContents(matrix, constraint.column, constraint.row);
        }

        protected List<JComponent> getCellContents(Matrix<Integer, List<JComponent>> matrix, int col, int row) {
            if (!matrix.contains(col, row)) {
                matrix.add(col, row, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return matrix.get(col, row);
        }

        protected Dimension getGridSize() {
            if (gridSize == null) {
                int maxCellWidth = 0;
                int maxCellHeight = 0;
                for (int row = 0; row < matrix.getRowCount(); row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < matrix.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                        List<JComponent> cell = getCellContents(matrix, col, row);
                        int cellWidth = 0;
                        int cellHeight = 0;
                        for (JComponent comp : cell) {
                            KeyConstraint kc = mapComponents.get(comp);
                            if (kc.span == 1) {
                                cellWidth = Math.max(cellWidth, comp.getPreferredSize().width);
                            }
                            cellHeight = Math.max(cellHeight, comp.getPreferredSize().height);
                        }
                        maxCellWidth = Math.max(cellWidth, maxCellWidth);
                        maxCellHeight = Math.max(cellHeight, maxCellHeight);
                    }
                }
                gridSize = new Dimension(maxCellWidth, maxCellHeight);
            }
            return gridSize;
        }

        protected int getRowHeight() {
            Dimension size = getGridSize();
            return size.height;
        }

        protected int getRowWidth(int row) {
            int rowWidth = 0;
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                Dimension size = getCellSize(col, row);
                rowWidth += size.width;
            }
            return rowWidth;
        }

        protected int getMaxRowWidth() {
            int rowWidth = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < matrix.getRowCount(); row++) {
                rowWidth = Math.max(getRowWidth(row), rowWidth);
            }
            return rowWidth;
        }

        protected int getColumnWidth(int col) {
            int width = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < matrix.getRowCount(); row++) {

                Dimension size = getCellSize(col, row);
                width = Math.max(size.width, width);

            }
            return width;
        }

        protected Dimension getCellSize(int col, int row) {
            List<JComponent> comps = matrix.get(col, row);
            Dimension size = new Dimension();
            size.height = getRowHeight();
            for (JComponent comp : comps) {
                Dimension subSize = getCellSize(col, row, comp);
                size.width = Math.max(size.width, subSize.width);
            }

            return size;
        }

        protected Dimension getCellSize(int col, int row, JComponent comp) {
            List<JComponent> comps = matrix.get(col, row);
            Dimension size = new Dimension();
            size.height = getRowHeight();
            int defaultWidth = getGridSize().width;
            KeyConstraint kc = mapComponents.get(comp);
            if (kc.span == 1) {
                size.width = defaultWidth;
            } else {
                int totalWidth = (int)Math.round(defaultWidth * kc.span);
                size.width = totalWidth;
            }

            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            int rowHeight = getRowHeight();
            int y = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < matrix.getRowCount(); row++) {
                int x = 0;
                for (int col = 0; col < matrix.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                    List<JComponent> comps = matrix.get(col, row);
                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
                    bounds.x = x;
                    bounds.y = y;
                    int maxWidth = 0;
                    for (JComponent comp : comps) {

                        Dimension size = getCellSize(col, row, comp);
                        bounds.setSize(size);
                        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, size.width);
                        comp.setBounds(bounds);

                    }
                    x += maxWidth;
                }
                y += rowHeight;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints) {
            if (constraints instanceof KeyConstraint) {
                mapComponents.put(comp, (KeyConstraint) constraints);
                mapConstraints.put((KeyConstraint) constraints, comp);
                getCellContents(matrix, (KeyConstraint) constraints).add((JComponent) comp);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension maximumLayoutSize(Container target) {
            return preferredLayoutSize(target);
        }

        @Override
        public float getLayoutAlignmentX(Container target) {
            return 0.5f;
        }

        @Override
        public float getLayoutAlignmentY(Container target) {
            return 0.5f;
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidateLayout(Container target) {
            gridSize = null;
        }

        public class Matrix<I, O> {

            private Map<I, Map<I, O>> mapRows;

            public Matrix() {
            }

            protected Map<I, Map<I, O>> getRowMap() {
                if (mapRows == null) {
                    mapRows = new HashMap<>(25);
                }
                return mapRows;
            }

            protected Map<I, O> getColumnMap(I row) {
                Map<I, Map<I, O>> rowMap = getRowMap();
                Map<I, O> mapCols = rowMap.get(row);
                if (mapCols == null) {
                    mapCols = new HashMap<>(25);
                    rowMap.put(row, mapCols);
                }
                return mapCols;
            }

            public void add(I col, I row, O obj) {
                Map<I, O> columnMap = getColumnMap(row);
                columnMap.put(col, obj);
            }

            public void remove(I col, I row, O obj) {
                if (contains(col, row)) {
                    Map<I, O> columnMap = getColumnMap(row);
                    columnMap.put(col, obj);
                }
            }

            public void removeColumn(I col) {
                for (I row : getRowMap().keySet()) {
                    Map<I, O> columnMap = getRowMap().get(row);
                    if (columnMap != null) {
                        columnMap.remove(col);
                    }
                }
            }

            public void removeRow(I row) {
                getRowMap().remove(row);
            }

            public int getRowCount() {
                return getRowMap().size();
            }

            public int getColumnCount() {
                int max = 0;
                for (I row : getRowMap().keySet()) {
                    Map<I, O> mapColumns = getRowMap().get(row);
                    max = Math.max(mapColumns.size(), max);
                }
                return max;
            }

            protected boolean containsRow(I row) {
                return getRowMap().containsKey(row);
            }

            protected boolean containsColumn(I col) {
                boolean contains = false;
                for (I row : getRowMap().keySet()) {
                    Map<I, O> columnMap = getRowMap().get(row);
                    if (columnMap != null && columnMap.containsKey(col)) {
                        contains = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return contains;
            }

            public boolean contains(I col, I row) {
                boolean contains = false;
                Map<I, O> colMap = getRowMap().get(row);
                if (colMap != null) {
                    if (colMap.containsKey(col)) {
                        contains = true;
                    }
                }

                return contains;
            }

            public O get(I col, I row) {
                O value = null;
                if (contains(col, row)) {
                    Map<I, O> columnMap = getRowMap().get(row);
                    value = columnMap.get(col);
                }
                return value;
            }

            public boolean contains(O value) {
                boolean contains = false;
                for (I row : getRowMap().keySet()) {
                    Map<I, O> mapColumns = getRowMap().get(row);
                    for (I col : mapColumns.keySet()) {
                        if (mapColumns.containsValue(value)) {
                            contains = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return contains;
            }

            public boolean rowContains(I row, O value) {
                boolean contains = false;
                Map<I, O> mapColumns = getRowMap().get(row);
                for (I col : mapColumns.keySet()) {
                    if (mapColumns.containsValue(value)) {
                        contains = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return contains;
            }

            public boolean columnContains(I column, O value) {
                boolean contains = false;
                for (I row : getRowMap().keySet()) {
                    Map<I, O> mapColumns = getRowMap().get(row);
                    O colValue = mapColumns.get(column);
                    if (colValue == value) {
                        contains = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return contains;
            }

            public O[] rowToArray(I row, O[] values) {
                List<O> lstValues = new ArrayList<O>(25);
                Map<I, O> mapColumns = getRowMap().get(row);
                lstValues.addAll(mapColumns.values());
                return lstValues.toArray(values);
            }

            public O[] columnToArray(I col, O[] values) {
                List<O> lstValues = new ArrayList<O>(25);
                for (I row : getRowMap().keySet()) {
                    Map<I, O> mapCols = getRowMap().get(row);
                    lstValues.add(mapCols.get(col));
                }
                return lstValues.toArray(values);
            }

            public Iterator<O> columnIterator(I col) {
                List<O> lstValues = new ArrayList<O>(25);
                for (I row : getRowMap().keySet()) {
                    Map<I, O> mapCols = getRowMap().get(row);
                    lstValues.add(mapCols.get(col));
                }
                return lstValues.iterator();
            }

            public Iterator<O> rowIterator(I row) {
                List<O> lstValues = new ArrayList<O>(25);
                Map<I, O> mapColumns = getRowMap().get(row);
                lstValues.addAll(mapColumns.values());
                return lstValues.iterator();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but seems like an overkill for a (seemingly) simple task. I'll get back to you "when all else fails..."

On a side-note, I now understand where you get your username from.

Comment: Great solution. +1 The layout only seems simple but it is not. It is in fact a good candidate for a custom layout. 
It could be easily done with MigLayout if it was possible to set size groups relatively to other groups. So far I have not figured it out.

Comment: I had quick look at MigLayout very quickly, but I don't have enough experience with it to get the results I wanted...

Comment: I was able to complete it by using a monospaced font, and by specifying the paddings and margins for the six keys. The final (un-minified?) code is 80 lines. Not the most elegant solution, but works well.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'b use matrix of JLabels (lots of, small, esp. thin, like as Border on top) in 1st. row with odd number of pixels, last with anchor (reduce empty space after resize, result how LayoutManager to divide all elements, GBC creating empty space at the end of) because GBC are column ...,  instead of whatever you doing with Dimension in your code and not accurate, but better than Oracle tutorial +1

Comment: Yeah, I tried using `GridBagLayout`, but ended it wasn't quite up to dealing with the multiple levels overlapping.  I also tried MigLayout, but I don't have enough experience with it make it work they way I wanted to and in frustration, wrote my own layout manager...which is a kind of horizontal grid like layout...

Answer (score 3):

Another approach. The only restriction is the use of a mono-spaced font to maintain the alignment.

```
import javax.swing.*;   // JFrame, JPanel, JLabel, JButton
import java.awt.*;      // GridBagLayout, GridBagConstraints, Insets, Font

public class Keyboard {
    private final JFrame f = new JFrame("Keyboard");

    private final JPanel keyboard = new JPanel();

    private static final String[][] key = {
        {"`", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "=", "Backspace"},
        {"Tab", "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "[", "]", "\\"},
        {"Caps", "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", ";", "'", "Enter"},
        {"Shift", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", ",", ".", "/", "\u2191"},
        {" ", "<", "\u2193", ">"}
    };

    public Keyboard() {
        keyboard.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        Insets zeroInset = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Font monospace = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12);

        JPanel pRow;
        JButton b;

        GridBagConstraints cRow = new GridBagConstraints(),
                           cButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        cRow.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        cButton.ipady = 21;

        // first dimension of the key array
        // representing a row on the keyboard
        for (int row = 0, i = 0; row < key.length; ++row) {
            pRow = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            cRow.gridy = row;

            // second dimension representing each key
            for (int col = 0; col < key[row].length; ++col, ++i) {

                // specify padding and insets for the buttons
                switch (key[row][col]) {
                    case "Backspace":   cButton.ipadx = 0; break;
                    case "Tab":         cButton.ipadx = 17; break;
                    case "Caps":        cButton.ipadx = 10; break;
                    case "Enter":       cButton.ipadx = 27; break;
                    case "Shift":       cButton.ipadx = 27; break;
                    case "/":
                        cButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 24);
                        break;
                    case " ":
                        cButton.ipadx = 247;
                        cButton.insets = new Insets(0, 192, 0, 72);
                        break;
                    default:
                        cButton.ipadx = 7;
                        cButton.insets = zeroInset;
                }

                b = new JButton(key[row][col]);
                b.setFont(monospace);
                b.setFocusable(false);
                pRow.add(b, cButton);
            }

            keyboard.add(pRow, cRow);
        }

        f.add(keyboard);
    }

    public void launch() {
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Keyboard ui = new Keyboard();
        ui.launch();
    }
}
```

[image: Swing Keyboard Layout]