# JButton does not change color when button is typed

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton, keylistener

I have a very small question. Now I wrote the code for creating a virtual keyboard. I want the color of the button to change when it is typed. Here is my code:

```
public class ButtonColor implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar()=='a') {
            A.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        
    }

}
```

]

Whenever I press A, nothing happens. When I add this line:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A was typed");
```

then type a, the message appears and after I click OK the button changes color. Why does that happen? How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: My immediate thoughts are, `KeyListener` is a poor choice for this...Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  You might consider having a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: I posted a picture of the displayed keyboard which does nothing.

Comment: Try overriding the KeyReleased method and put your code in keyReleased.

Comment: it worked!  but the specific button needs to be pressed by the mouse first... Say you click the button with your mouse, it gets selected, then you type 'a' and the color changes. If this does not make sense tell me and I'll post a picture. I need it to change the color without the mouse being pressed.

Comment: If it only works after you click the button then it sounds like then you may have a focus issue, try using key bindings instead. With key listeners the specific component that you added a listener too will have to have focus to work.

Comment: do you have both implementations? like do you have code in both keyRealeased and keyTyped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be any number of reasons why this doesn't work for you, for starters, the button may be transparent (`opaque == false`)

I would strongly recommend against `KeyListener` in favour of [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as `KeyListener` has issues with focus...

For example...

The following uses the key bindings API in order to respond to a given key stroke, depending on if it's a key press or release event, it will set the background color and opacity state accordingly and even sets the buttons pressed state...

[image: Keyboard]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class KeyboardTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new KeyboardTest();
    }

    public KeyboardTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JButton btnA = createButton("A");
            JButton btnB = createButton("B");
            JButton btnC = createButton("C");
            JButton btnD = createButton("D");
            JButton btnE = createButton("E");

            add(btnA);
            add(btnB);
            add(btnC);
            add(btnD);
            add(btnE);

            addKeyBinding(btnA, "A", KeyEvent.VK_A);
            addKeyBinding(btnB, "B", KeyEvent.VK_B);
            addKeyBinding(btnC, "C", KeyEvent.VK_C);
            addKeyBinding(btnD, "D", KeyEvent.VK_D);
            addKeyBinding(btnE, "E", KeyEvent.VK_E);

        }

        protected JButton createButton(String text) {
            JButton btn = new JButton(text);
            btn.setFocusable(false);
            return btn;
        }

        protected void addKeyBinding(JButton btn, String name, int virtualKey) {
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(virtualKey, 0, false), name + ".pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(virtualKey, 0, true), name + ".released");

            am.put(name + ".pressed", new KeyAction(btn, true));
            am.put(name + ".released", new KeyAction(btn, false));
        }

    }

    public class KeyAction extends AbstractAction {

        private JButton btn;
        private boolean highlight;

        public KeyAction(JButton btn, boolean highlight) {
            this.btn = btn;
            this.highlight = highlight;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (highlight) {
                btn.getModel().setPressed(true);
                btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
                btn.setOpaque(true);
            } else {
                btn.getModel().setPressed(false);
                btn.setBackground(null);
                btn.setOpaque(false);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Updated**

If you also use `btn.getModel().setArmed(...);` you will get a much more "bolded" response, which produces better visual feedback...IMHO

Comment: @RJadhav It's a runnable example which demonstrates a concept, if it was wall of code, I'd have included [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622279/laying-out-a-keyboard-in-swing/24625704#24625704) as the bases ;)

Comment: lol..just kidding..it seems you have working code for every other java question on so..awesome!!

Comment: @RJadhav Comes from not having a life ;)

Comment: Well that's subjective and debatable..whats life for you may not be the same for everyone.. :D