# Swing Button Look and Feel Based On Size?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have made a JButton:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
```

Then added it to a JPanel:

```
panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Photo of the Button:

[image: JButton]

I have noticed 2 different types of JButtons:

[image: thin] [image: thick]

I like the button titled "OK", is there any way I can set this as the preferred style of the button? Or if this can not be done, is there a way to make a panel with a fixed height, and add it to the center of another panel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overrride `getPreferredSize()` method but I never suggest you to use it. It's required only  in case of [custom painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

```
JButton btn = new JButton(){
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(40, 40);
    }
};
```

Comment: Beware of this kind of [pitfall](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513) when substituting an arbitrary size for the UI delegate's preferred size.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could just set the margins of the button, and let the layout manager determine the preferred size *for* you.

   ```
   button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 30, 0, 30));
                       // top, left, bottom, right
   ```
2. Make sure the container you add the button to, has a layout manager that respects preferred sizes of its components. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376596/2587435) to see which layouts will and wont respect the preferred sizes

Answer (score 1):

Use a layout that respects the preferred size calculated by the button's UI delegate. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/230513), each button is added to a panel having `FlowLayout`; the button retains its preferred size. In contrast, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513) adds buttons to a `GridLayout`; resize the enclosing container to see the effect. A helpful guide is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622005/230513).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a style. You have to define size of `JButton`.

```
JButton btn = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
```

Comment: Don't use `setPreferredSize()` method.

Comment: Read it here [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)